# DataTable when Null/Empty data being fetched

Tags: jquery, jsp, spring-mvc, datatable

I am using `Spring MVC` and `DataTable with jQuery` for tabling and related stuffs.

I get following error when none of the data is available.

```
DataTables warning (table id='results'): Requested unknown parameter '1' from the data source for row 0
```

I searched on the internet and found that number of columns might have a mismatch which is not the case. But yes, sometimes, data is null/empty so there is nothing to render in the UI. We don't even show the table in that case.

But this error comes all the time. I just started DataTables and using default behavior :

```
jq(document).ready( function(){
        jq("#results").dataTable();          
    });
```

My table code is like this:

```
<table border="1" style="font-size:12px;width: 868px; table-layout: fixed; word-wrap: break-word;border-collapse: collapse" id='results'>
<thead>
   <tr>
    <th>Batch Name</th>
    <th>Batch User</th>
    <th>Total URL Count</th>
    <th>Submitted URL Count</th>
    <th>Processed URL Count</th>
    <th>Submission Time</th>
    <th>Batch Status</th>
    <th>Download Link</th>
  </tr>
 </thead>
  <tbody id="orderbody">
   <tr id="pattern" style="display:none" >
    <td width="15%"><span  id="ibatchName">Batch Name</span></td>
    <td width="15%"><span  id="ibatchUser">Batch User</span></td>
    <td width="11%"><span  id="iTotalUrlCount" >Total URL Count</span></td>
    <td width="11%"><span  id="iSubmittedURLCount" >Submitted URL Count</span></td>
    <td width="11%"><span  id="iProcessedURLCount">Processed URL Count</span></td>
    <td width="11%"><span  id="iSubmissionTime" >Submission Time</span></td>
    <td width="11%"><span  id="ibatchStatus" >Batch Status</span></td>
    <td width="15%"><span  id="iDownloadLink" >Download Link</span></td>
    </tr>

    <c:choose>
    <c:when test="${  not empty batches}">
    <c:forEach var='batchDetail' items='${batches}'>
     <tr id="pattern0">
    <td>${batchDetail.batchName}</td>
    <td>${batchDetail.batchUser}</td>
    <td>${batchDetail.totalUrlCount}</td>
    <td>${batchDetail.submittedUrlCount}</td>
    <td>${batchDetail.processedUrlCount}</td>
    <td>${batchDetail.submissionTimeFormatted}</td>
    <td>${batchDetail.batchStatus}</td>
    <td>${batchDetail.downloadLink}</a></td>
   </tr>
    </c:forEach>    
    </c:when>

    <c:otherwise>
    <tr id="pattern0">
    <td colspan="8"><span class="batch_not_found">You are not authorized to see any of the batches. </span></td>
    </tr>
    </c:otherwise>
</c:choose>
   </tbody>   
  </table>
```

What should I do? Is there any way to disable this warning when no data is fetched?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the answer myself!

```
<tr id="pattern0">
    <td colspan="8"><span class="batch_not_found">You are not authorized to see any of the batches. </span></td>
    </tr>
```

is the issue. DataTable is unable to render it. Moved it outside the table and it worked.